# Convert image png to jpg with Magento

Tags: image, magento, png, jpeg

i try to convert an image png in jpg in a custom module with Magento.
The upload works but when i try to convert the pic there is a prblm. There isn't method to convert in the Varien_file_uploader but in the Varien_image there is.
I try that :

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');              
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg'));
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
$uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['name']);   

$image = new Varien_Image($path . DS . $_FILES['image']['name']);
$image->convert('jpeg');
$image->save($path, 'mypic.jpeg');
```

Any ideas ?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

I created a function, you can use it as helper. If someone need it :)

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Helper_Image_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

    public function convert($ext, $path, $name, $newname = NULL)
    {
        $exploded = explode('.',$name);
        $extoriginal = $exploded[count($exploded) - 1];

        switch($extoriginal)
        {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path . $name);
            break;
            case 'png':
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($path . $name);
            break;
            case 'gif':
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($path . $name);
            break;
            case 'bmp':
                $image = imagecreatefrombmp($path . $name);
            break;
        }

        $bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
        imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
        imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        imagedestroy($image);
        $quality = 100;

        $newname = ($newname == NULL) ? $exploded[0] : $newname;

        switch($ext)
        {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                $newimage = $path . $newname . ".jpg";
                imagejpeg($bg, $newimage, $quality);
            break;
            case 'png':
                $newimage = $path . $newname . ".png";
                imagepng($bg, $newimage, $quality);
            break;
            case 'gif':
                $newimage = $path . $newname . ".gif";
                imagegif($bg, $newimage, $quality);
            break;
            case 'bmp':
                $newimage = $path . $newname . ".bmp";
                imagewbmp($bg, $newimage, $quality);
            break;
        }
        imagedestroy($bg);
        return $newimage;
    }
}
```

In the config.xml (of your custom module) add this in the global node

```
    <helpers>
        <news>
            <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Helper_Image</class>
        </news>
    </helpers>
```

And to use

```
$helper = Mage::helper('YourModule');
$helper->convert('jpg', $path, $yourimage);
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

there is not idea for magento function but following is php function that will  convert a PNG to JPG with the transparency in white.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagedestroy($image);
$quality = 50; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
imagejpeg($bg, $filePath . ".jpg", $quality);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

Comment: Hey, thx for your reply. I know how to do in PHP, but i'll be surprised if no function exist with Magento to do it !

Comment: there is no function to convert image in magento